# Query based on dropdown selection with google maps GeoLocation

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to run a query based on a dropdown value posted from the html but I can't manage to get it to work.

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <select name="nearest">
                <option name="distance" value="5">5km</option>
                <option name="distance" value="10">10km</option>
                <option name="distance" value="25">25km</option>
                <option name="distance" value="50">50km</option>
                <option name="distance" value="100">100km</option>    
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="filterNow" value="Filter" id="filterbutton">
    </form>
```

**This is my PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['filterNow'])){
    $selectedDistance = $_POST['nearest'];
    $q =  "SELECT id, name, image_url, description, price, lat, lng, rating, owner, free, city, ROUND(( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $_POST['userLat']   . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $_POST['userLng'] . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $_POST['userLat'] . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ), 2) AS distance FROM places HAVING distance < " . $selectedDistance . " ORDER BY distance ASC";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($linkNew, $q);
}
        echo "<h2>Nearest Places</h2>";
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
        echo "<h2>" . $row1[1] . "</h2><br />"; 
    }
```

If I replace the $selectedDistance with a number and remove the form in the html and the if-loop in the php, it shows me the places within that amount of kilometers, but it doesnt work with the dropdown

Comment: Have you forgotten about `$_POST['userLat']` and `$_POST['userLng']`?

Comment: They are being posted from the javascript Google Maps API, they return the user lat and lng, if I just put the query without the post of the dropdown, it works just fine, but I want the user to be able to select the nearest spots by distance

Comment: So what's the output of `echo $q;` - all looks ok?

Comment: The output of the query does not look allright, it doesn't seem to be able to pick up the values from $_POST['userLat'] and $_POST['userLng']. They aere just empty. The thing is, if I remove the form with the select and remove the "if (isset($_POST['filterNow'])){}" from the PHP and just add a default number to distance(e.g. 50 for 50 kilometers) it works just fine and it does pick up the values. Is it possible that the form with the select is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be causing you an issue.

The option tag does not have a name attribute so change them all to :-

```
<option value="5">5km</option>
```

Also if you ever get issues with the data passed to a script using $_POST or $_GET just dump the $_POST/GET onto the browser and have a look at what is actually in it using `var_dump($_POST);`

So before this line add a var_dump

```
var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['filterNow'])){
```

and you will get $_POST displayed on the browser, or my preference

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
if (isset($_POST['filterNow'])){
```

If the probelem is not obvious add the dumped output to you question and we can have another guess.